# Python file chunk in json

Tags: python, json, django, utf-8

I have some service api and need to upload file by chunks in json format.

Here is example of code:

```
    for chunk in file_content.chunks():
        chunkSize = len(chunk)
        d = {'chunksize': chunkSize, 'chunk': chunk}
        dump = json.dumps(d)
```

But getting:

```
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 11: invalid start byte
```

How can i fix it or maybe ignore?

Note: I cannot change the api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.dumps` takes [a number of arguments](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html#json.dumps), setting `ensure_ascii` to false should do the trick.

`dump = json.dumps(d, ensure_ascii=False)`

Comment: Thanks! I found it before, but used in a wrong place.